# Loading JPGs into a neural network: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python

Can someone please shed some light on what is wrong with my code and what exactly is causing this error? I'm a Python beginner and I'd like to load some JPGs into this network. Mostly I've been trying to work out problems by trial and error and troubleshooting on this website. This stuff is hurting my brain so please help out a newbie.

Thank you in advance!

Darren

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gan3.py", line 30, in <module>
content = open(os.path.join(path, filename)).read()
File "/Users/darren/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in 
decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: 
invalid start byte
```

The code:

```
def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images
    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages
path = "input_data"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    content = open(os.path.join(path, filename)).read()
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
      text = f.read()
```

Cheers guys!

Comment: There is just too much code that is irrelevant to the problem. Please reduce the code to a Minimal, Verifiable example.

Comment: Ok, I edited it using the last traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `open` opens files in text mode. When you read from it, Python automatically tries to convert your data to strings, which fails at this isn't an UTF-8 encoded text.

If it is an image, you have to open it in binary mode:

```
content = open(os.path.join(path, filename), mode='rb').read()
```

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, note that if you feel that an answer you received has solved your problem, you may accept (checkmark on the left) and/or upvote (up arrow) it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIL library to open image files:

```
from PIL import Image
#<----code---->
content = Image.open(os.path.join(path, filename))
```